# What needs to be enqueued into WordPress to use the jQuery-ui ".accordion" function?

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery-ui

I want to use the jQuery-ui `.accordion` function in a WordPress child theme. So far I've:

1. created a js file in my child theme directory and put it in no-conflict mode:
   `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion();
   });`
2. Enqueued the script into my functions.php file: `function myChild_scripts() {
        wp_enqueue_style( 'onepage-child-style', get_stylesheet_uri() );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'onepage-child-accordion', get_stylesheet_uri() . '/js/accordion.js', array('jquery-ui-accordion', 'jquery'), 20150507, true );`
3. Added the `add_action` function: `add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'myChild_scripts' );`

However, the `.accordion` function is also dependent on `jquery-ui.css`. Don't I also need to include that in the enqueueing process? I can find no documentation that discusses inclusion of this file - or whether it's already part of WP core.

Answer (score 0):

You can enqueue a stylesheet in the functions.php file. It may be something like this (assuming your file is in your theme directory, inside a css folder).

```
function my_styles()
{
    wp_register_style( 'jquery-ui-style', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/jquery-ui.css', 'all' );
    wp_enqueue_style( 'jquery-ui-style' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_styles' );
```

Here's [some reference](http://www.pixafy.com/blog/2013/06/how-to-enqueue-a-custom-stylesheet-via-functions-php-in-wordpress).